# Getting Error :: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

```
function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address recipient) public Restricted{
```

Getting error:

> Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed. Request memory newRequest = Request({
>
> | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

```
Request memory newRequest = Request({       //error here
    description: description,
    value: value,
    recipient: recipient,
    complete: false,
    approvers: 0
});
            
requests.push(newRequest);
```

Comment: did you check this? This question is already answered. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87451/solidity-error-struct-containing-a-nested-mapping-cannot-be-constructed